# Incompatible shapes of TimeseriesGenerator feed and Dense layer - Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I have some dimension issues when I am using the `Dense` layer in combination with `TimeseriesGenerator`.

My training data looks like this:

`X = (1 000 000, 6)`

`y = (1 000 000, 2)`

I put all of this in `TimeseriesGenerator`:

`train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=4, batch_size=32, stride=1)`

and I receive:

```
train_gen[0][0].shape
(32, 4, 6)

train_gen[0][1].shape
(32, 2)
```

afterwards I created a simple model:

```
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(4,6), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer= optimizer, metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'accuracy'])
```

and the last step - fitting data:

```
mw = model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

Now I get an error. The last layer has a dimension issue:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [32,4,2] vs. [32,2] [Op:Sub] name: loss/dense_44_loss/sub/
```

I assume the model wants to compare the [32,4,2] shaped output of the model with the given [32,2] shaped training data.

I haven't found a solution yet. I think I definitely need the `TimeseriesGenerator` due to the size of my original dataset which has 160 billion samples and I don't have enough RAM. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last layer has a dimensionality error, which you can simply fix by adding a Flatten() layer like this:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop

X = np.random.rand(996, 6)
y = np.random.rand(996, 2)

t_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=4, batch_size=32, stride=1)

optimizer = RMSprop()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_shape=(4,6), activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))

model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', 
    optimizer= optimizer, 
    metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'accuracy'])


mw = model.fit_generator(generator=t_gen, epochs=1, verbose=1)
```

The result will be like this:

```
Epoch 1/1
31/31 [==============================] - 0s 12ms/step - loss: 0.2817 - mean_absolute_error: 0.2817 - accuracy: 0.4748
```

Your new model is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `TimeseriesGenerator` is used for creating 3D data for timeseries applications and then you use `LSTM` to process this 3D data.

You can still use the `TimeseriesGenerator` together with `Dense` layers with some hacks.

Change the `length` of the `TimeseriesGenerator` to be `1`.

```
train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(X, y, length=1, batch_size=32, stride=1)
#shapes : train_gen[0][0] : (32,1,6)
```

Now your data is essentially a 2D data and that middle dimension is just useless. So just create a `Lambda layer` which drops this middle dimension in your model as the first layer.

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.layers import Lambda


optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda inp: K.squeeze(inp, axis=1),input_shape=(1,6)))
model.add(Dense(12, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(40, activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='tanh'))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer= optimizer, metrics=['mean_absolute_error', 'accuracy'])

print(model.output_shape) #(None,2)
```

Your model output shape must match with your labels shape.

```
mw = model.fit_generator(generator=train_gen, epochs=1, verbose=1) #runs
```